# Push ribbon div to right edge of screen

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am designing a site that has a specific requirement to display a ribbon to the far right of the screen, I am using Bootstrap and the ribbon is in a bootstrap container, with a row and columns divided equally between the two elements, I want the Designer Text to stay exactly where it is because I am trying to keep it responsive and contained when going to mobile. How can I push the image div (Ribbon) all the way to the far right extending outside of the container.

I have include an image below of what I am working with. I may be doing this completely wrong, as my design skills are minimal.

[image]

I would like it to look like this

[image]

Here is the code:

```css
.bookmarkRibbon {
  /*width:100%;*/ 
  height: 0;
  width: 100%;
  border-bottom: 22px solid #ff5750;
  border-top: 22px solid #ff5750;
  border-left: 20px solid transparent;
  position: absolute;
  margin-right: -3000px;
}

.bookmarkRibbon a {
  display: block;
  padding: 0;
  position: relative;
  /* allows us to position our pseudo-elements properly */

  background: #ff5750;
  overflow: visible;
  /*height: -18px;*/
  margin-left: 29px;
  margin-top: -18px;
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: x-large;      
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-7">                    
      <h1 ID="lblCategoryName" runat="server"></h1>                    
    </div> 
    <div class="col-xs-5">
      <div class="bookmarkRibbon" id="discountBannerContainer" runat="server" style="margin-top: 15px">
        <a href="/pure-css-ribbon-banner.html#" id="ribbon">20% OFF ADDRESS STAMPS</a><p class="mine">CODE: STAMP 20</p>
      </div>                                     
    </div>          
  </div> 
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to move the ribbon outside the container to be child of `body`.
Than you can position it absolute.

```
<body>
  <div class="ribbon"></div>
</body

.ribbon {
  position: absolute;
  top: 300px;
  right: 0;
}
```

If you can not move the ribbon outside the container you have to use position fixed.
Unfortunately the ribbon will scroll with your page.

```
.ribbon {
  position: fixed;
  top: 300px;
  right: 0;
}
```

Last option would be to use negative values and use the calc function.
This is not quite ease but doable.
Do you have a link to your site? I could take a looke at it if you like to.

Comment: I will try that, and I don't have a link yet working in a development environment for my employer, but let me give that a try.